# Why does the CSS change in my RoR app depending on whether I run it in production or development?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, dev-to-production

There are a few problems that I encounter when I run in production which aren't there in development, for example I have a dropdown menu, which looks as I intended when I run in development: Only the Menu button is visible, and the options below it are hidden until hover or focus. There are also no bullet points. However when I run in production I get bullet points on every `<li>`, and my previously hidden options are now displayed in a big mess below my Menu `<button>`.

HTML:

```
<nav class="dropdown-nav" role="navigation">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn--action" aria-haspopup="true"><%= t('menu') %></button>
      <ul class="dropdown" aria-label="submenu">
        <% if logged_in? %>
          ....
        <% else %>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to(t('signup'), signup_path) %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to(t('login'), login_path) %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

scss:

```
.main-menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  & li {
    display: block;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;

    &:hover,
    &:focus-within {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    &:hover > ul,
    &:focus-within > ul,
    & ul:hover,
    & ul:focus {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}

.dropdown {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: none;

  padding: 0.2rem;
  background-color: $off-white;
  min-width: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-item {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;

  &:hover,
  &:focus-within {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Editing to add my config/environments/production.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "Appear_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: Most likely, you're using multiple CSS files and only some are loading. Can you use the Inspector to see if CSS files are missing in production? Or where the "lost" rules are defined in dev?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [sass ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) wrong.

```
.main-menu {
  &:li {
    display: block;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    ...
  }
}
```

Compiles down to:

```
li.main-menu 
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  ...
}
```

While you want:

```
.main-menu li
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  ...
}
```

Which you will get if you just remove the ampersand:

```
.main-menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  li {
    display: block;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;

    &:hover,
    &:focus-within {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    &:hover > ul,
    &:focus-within > ul,
    ul:hover,
    ul:focus {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Use the ampersand when you want to add rules to the current selector. Use regular nesting to define rules for child elements.

Comment: I'm not really going to go into why it would work locally and not in production but my guess is that you're not running the same code.

Comment: Thanks very much you are absolutely right that I have made a mistake there with the apersand, but having now changed it to match your suggestion, the problem persists.

Comment: Well the answer to that is a lot more complicated and can only really be resolved with a debugging effort on your part. You need to ensure that the production server is actually serving the same CSS and that its not due to a code parity issue or failed assets compilation.